# adding a header to a parsed csv - c#

Tags: parsing, csv, header

I have parsed a csv file using the oledb csv parser. 
However, my csv doesn't have an header, and so when I fill it to a datatable/dataset, the first row of the data becomes the header and I can't write it to Access.

how can I create headers for the parsed csv so I could write the first row as well?

thanks,
Udi

Answer (score 0):

Add `HDR=No` to the `Extended Properties` of [the connection string](http://www.connectionstrings.com/textfile).